# how to refresh only a form or fieldset not a page

Tags: javascript, html, dom

in my SPRING project, I have an index.html file that has two forms. When you write a name in the first one and click submit the name is transferred to another one. The other form is connected with DB and displays it in a fieldset.

I have two buttons:
1)ADD to DB - when I ADD an item I can see it right away
2)DELETE an item from DB by ID - it works and deletes from DB, but the view isn't refreshed/reloaded. I need to refresh the whole page to see the results of DELETED item.
When I refresh the page it is going back to the first form with the name...

I wonder how to solve it.

I know something must be written inside the DELETE function.

PLEASE HELP.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:https="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:http="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SHOPPING LIST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css"
          integrity="sha384-nn4HPE8lTHyVtfCBi5yW9d20FjT8BJwUXyWZT9InLYax14RDjBj46LmSztkmNP9w" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<main style="width: 40%; margin: 0 auto">
    <div id="welcome" style="text-align: center">
        <h1>Introduce yourself</h1>
    </div>
    <form id="welcomeForm" class="pure-form pure-g pure-form-aligned">
       <input class="pure-input-rounded pure-u-1" name="name" placeholder="name" id="text_name">
       <button id="welcomeFormBtn" class="pure-button pure-button-primary pure-u-1">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <form id="AddForm" class="pure-form" style="text-align: center; display: none">
        <fieldset>
            <input id="name" class="pure-input-rounded pure-input-2-3" style="width: available" placeholder="name">
            <input id="amount" class="pure-input-rounded pure-input-2-3" style="width: available" placeholder="amount">
            <input id="uom" class="pure-input-rounded pure-input-2-3" style="width: available" placeholder="unit of measure">
            <input id="idToDel" type="number" class="pure-input-rounded pure-input-2-3" style="width: available" placeholder="Please provide an id to delete">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <button id="addProduct" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">POST</button>
            <button id="delProduct" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">DELETE</button>
            <br>
            <button id="print-btn"  style="width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius: 50%"><img style="width: 40px; height: 40px" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/3233/3233446.png" alt="PRINT"></button>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="allProducts" >
          </fieldset>
    </form >
</main>
<script>
    const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080';
    const API_URL_ADD = `${API_URL}/api`;
    const API_URL_ALL = `${API_URL_ADD}/list`;
    const pName = document.getElementById('name');
    const pUom = document.getElementById('uom');
    const pAmount = document.getElementById('amount');

    AddFunction();

    fetch(API_URL_ALL)
        .then(processOkResponse)
        .then(list => list.forEach(createNewProduct))

    document.getElementById('addProduct').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch(API_URL_ALL, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ name: pName.value, type : pUom.value, amount: pAmount.value })
        })
            .then(processOkResponse)
            .then(createNewProduct)
            .then(() => pName.value = '')
            .then(() => pAmount.value = '')
            .then(() => pUom.value = '')
            .catch(console.warn);
    });

    function createNewProduct(product) {
        const label = document.createElement('label');
        const l1 = document.createElement('label');
        const l2 = document.createElement('label');
        const l3 = document.createElement('label');
        const l4 = document.createElement('label');
        label.classList.add('label');
        l1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`  ID:${product.id}. `));
        l2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(` ${product.name} `));
        l3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(` ${product.amount} `));
        l4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(` ${product.type} `));
        label.appendChild(l1).appendChild(l2).appendChild(l3).appendChild(l4)
        document.getElementById('allProducts').appendChild(label);
        label.style.display= 'table';
        label.style.paddingLeft='40%';
        label.style.wordSpacing='30%';
            }

    document.getElementById('delProduct').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        removeTodo();
    });

    function removeTodo() {
        const d = document.getElementById('idToDel').value;
        fetch(`${API_URL_ALL}/${d}`, { method: 'DELETE' })
            .then(processOkResponse)
            .catch(console.info)
    }

    function AddFunction(){
        const welcomeForm = document.getElementById('welcomeForm');

        document.getElementById('welcomeFormBtn').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const formObj = {
                name: welcomeForm.elements.name.value,
            };
            fetch(`${API_URL_ADD}?${new URLSearchParams(formObj)}`)
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then((text) => {
                    document.getElementById('welcome').innerHTML = `
                <h1>${text}</h1>
            `;
                    welcomeForm.remove();
                    document.getElementById('AddForm').style.display = 'block';
                    });
        });
    }

    document.getElementById('print-btn').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const f = document.getElementById("allProducts").innerHTML;
        const a = window.open();
        a.document.write(document.getElementById('welcome').innerHTML);
        a.document.write(f);
        a.print();
    })

    function processOkResponse(response = {}) {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        }
        throw new Error(`Status not 200 (${response.status})`);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make a function that refreshes the page and then add this to it `welcomeForm.remove();
                    document.getElementById('AddForm').style.display = 'block';` Then add that function to the delete function.

Comment: I tried with windwo.location.reload(); welcomeForm.remove();                     document.getElementById('AddForm').style.display = 'block'; I've also added this new function to removeTodo function as you mentioned, but It stucks at first form - welcomeForm and nothing happens

Comment: it should be window.location.reload() :D

Answer (score 0):

just like you've done `.then(processOkResponse).then(createNewProduct)` for adding a product, you should do the same for deletion as well.
`.then(processOkResponse).then(deleteProduct)` in your `removeToDo` function as well.

You should add a specific id to the label you're creating in createNewProduct(product) function like this

```
function createNewProduct(product) {
        const label = document.createElement('label');
        label.setAttribute('id', `pid-${product.id}`); // just this line to be added
        //.... rest of your code
```

```
function deleteProduct(deleteApiResponse) {
   // make sure to send id value of the deleted product
   const {id} = deleteApiResponse;
   const idToDel = `pid-${id}`;
   // this does remove from HTML. just sets display: none
   document.getElementById(idToDel).style.display = 'none';

   // or remove from HTML like this. but for this you need the parentId 
   // to effectively remove the style(if any) on the id to be delete
   //document.getElementById(idToDelParent).innerHTML = '';
  
}
```

Comment: Don't work. Is 'idToDel' near the name of the function just a name or should it refer to document.getElemtById('idToDel').value ? I've tried both doesn't help at all, and what is idToDelParent should I declare it?

Comment: Maybe there is a way to clear the fieldset id= 'allProducts' and then recall/fill it again with DB items?

Comment: idToDel should come from delete api's response and that should refer to the label element you're trying to delete. have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I did it as you said, but... results are the same. Hibernate tells me that "product has been deleted", but is still visible :(